# What is the meaning of $$1 in bash?

Tags: bash

I am actually playing with arguments and its happened. I just thought like to see what will happen if I type `$$1` and I did it and got something below.

```
raja@raja-BONEFISH:~$ $$1
19301: command not found
```

What's that 19301 mean, is it telling something?

Bottom-Line: what does meaning for `$$1` in bash.

Comment: ouch!! that much easy thing. I am still have many things to learn. All answers are super. +1 to all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$$` is the PID (process id) of the current process.

`$$1` is the above PID followed by the literal string `1`.

So it is telling you that your `bash` is the process with PID 1930.

But... free trick:

```
show() { eval echo \$$1; }
show PATH
/home/romano/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

(quite convoluted, ain't it?)

More info in [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html).

Comment: See also - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: For a moment I read the TLDP as "Too Long Didn't Pee".

Answer (score 13):

- `$$` - pid of the current shell (not subshell) - see [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/2353900)
- `$$1` - pid of the current shell (not subshell) followed by `1`.
- `$$2` - pid of the current shell (not subshell) followed by `2`.
- `$$a` - pid of the current shell (not subshell) followed by `a` character.
- And so on...

See the output of `echo $$1`.

And you get the error `command not found` because you are trying to execute a string composed of digits which obviously is not a command.

Answer (score 10):

You have concatenated `$$` and `1` together to get the PID of the current shell and `1`, i.e. `$$` stands for the PID of the currently running shell and `1` is just a character, you could do `$$a`, `$$@` to get the PID concatenated with the following character.

Answer (score 6):

$$ it will state `1930` which is **pid** of current shell .

When you type `$$1` that means pid followed by one so you the output would be `19301` .

Try `$$2` the output will be `19302`